# Card matching game.. how to compare cards?

Tags: .net, vb.net, comparison-operators, playing-cards

So my design is to have 26 picture boxes (code only shows till 10.. you get the idea) to show the user their "hand". Now how do I check those image boxes for doubles, and then remove those doubles to a cleared pile? So let's say if there are 2 Jacks, and 3 fives then 2 Jacks are removed and only 2 fives are removed. I can't figure out how to do this. I have them set up and named in my code below as follows:

```
Dim faces() As String = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
         "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}
```

Here is my code, this is really just for player one although there will be a computer player as well.

Deckofcards

```
Public Class DeckOfCards
   Private Const NUMBER_OF_CARDS As Integer = 52 ' number of cards
   Private deck(NUMBER_OF_CARDS - 1) As Card ' array of Card objects
   Private currentCard As Integer ' index of next Card to be dealt
   Private Shared randomNumbers As New Random() ' random number generator

   ' constructor fills deck of Cards
   Public Sub New()
      Dim faces() As String = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
         "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}
      Dim suits() As String = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"}
        currentCard = 0 ' set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck(0)


      ' populate deck array with Card objects
      For count = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
         deck(count) = New Card(faces(count Mod 13), suits(count \ 13))
      Next
   End Sub ' New

   ' shuffle deck of Cards with simple one-pass algorithm
   Public Sub Shuffle()
      ' after shuffling, dealing should start at deck(0) again
      currentCard = 0 ' reinitialize currentCard

      ' for each Card, pick another random Card and swap them
      For first = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
         ' select a random number between 0 and 51
         Dim second As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS)

         ' swap current Card with randomly selected Card
         Dim temp As Card = deck(first) ' store copy of deck(first)
         deck(first) = deck(second) ' move deck(second) to deck(first)
         deck(second) = temp ' move original deck(first) to deck(second)
      Next
   End Sub ' Shuffle

   ' deal one Card
   Public Function DealCard() As Card
      ' determine whether Cards remain to be dealt
      If currentCard <= deck.GetUpperBound(0) Then
         Dim lastCard As Integer = currentCard ' store current card number
         currentCard += 1 ' increment current card number 
         Return deck(lastCard)
      Else
         Return Nothing ' no more cards to deal
        End If



    End Function ' DealCard


End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

I Think you are going about this the wrong way. ie Your design is wrong because you are assigning values as strings which makes comparing them more difficult

I would recommend you have a `Card` class that looks like this:

```
Public Class Card

    Public Enum CardValue
        Ace = 1
        Two = 2
        'etc
        Jack = 11
        Queen = 12
        King = 13
    End Enum

    Public Enum CardSuit
        Clubs 
        Spades
        Hearts
        Diamonds 
    End Enum

    Public Property Value As CardValue
    Public Property Suit as CardSuit

    Public sub New(value as CardValue, suit as CardSuit)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Suit = suit
    End Sub

End Class
```

The each play would simple have a `List(Of Card)` in their hand. To compare which ones are the same is as simple as:

```
Dim Cards as List(Of Card) 'Players hand

If Cards.Select(Function(x) x.Value).Distinct.Count < Cards.Count Then
    'there are some duplicates in the list
    Dim duplicates = Cards.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Value).Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key).ToList
    For Each i In duplicates
        Debug.WriteLine("Card value " + i.ToString + " is a match")
    Next
End If
```

You can create and populate your deck of cards as follows:

```
Dim deck(51) As Card
Dim cardPosition As Integer = 0

'loop through each suit and each value in that suit setting one of the deck to that    
For Each suit As Card.CardSuit In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Card.CardSuit))
    For Each value As Card.CardValue In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Card.CardValue))
        deck(cardPosition) = New Card(value, suit)
        cardPosition += 1
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You could make your loop more efficient (and remove the `If`) if you loop `j` from `i + 1` (and `i` to `Cards.Count-2`) instead...  Not sure your change from `string` or `int` to an `enum` makes significant difference to the problem, though it's definitely nicer code!

Comment: @dan - agreed - Have modified this for a linq query which may be slightly more efficient

Comment: @MattWilko Thanks for the help, I'm getting an error though by replacing the card class "Error 1 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'DeckOfCardsTest.Card.CardValue'." and "Error 2 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'DeckOfCardsTest.Card.CardSuit'." for this part of the code ' populate deck array with Card objects
      For count = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
            deck(count) = New Card(faces(count Mod 13), suits(count \ 13))
      Next

Comment: @user2382959 - see my edited post on how to populate your deck

Comment: @MattWilko I am very grateful for your continued help! When I replaced the problem code with the new code you gave me, clicking 'deal' no longer displays the images. Also, where do I put the List(of card) code? I get the error Variable 'Cards' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime and the program crashes.

Comment: @user2382959 - I suggest you start a new question if you are having trouble with some other issue. Don't forget to mark my answer if it has helped you.